# Оборачивание разнородных моделей во вьюмодели

Tags: c#, mvvm

Проблема такая, есть абстрактный класс модели от которого наследуется энное количество конкретных моделей, у них у всех кроме некоторых общих есть куча своих полей, к каждому ассоциируется своя соответствующая `View`, проблема начинает в том, что каждый экземпляр нужно обернуть в соответствующую `ViewModel` (вьюихи то разные, и поведение у них отличается) - сейчас у меня этим занимается отдельная функция, в ней определен `switch` в который добавляются условия по мере написания новых классов с такой сигнатурой:

```
public static TaskViewModelBase GetTaskViewModel(TaskBase tsk, IDataTask taskDataService)
```

Вся эта дурь сильно попахивает, как вы понимаете. Имеется ли какое-то элегантное решение или выбранная архитектура вообще ни к черту?

Comment: Хм. У вас почему-то однозначное соответствие моделей и вью-моделей. Обычно это не так, любая VM может пользоваться несколькими моделями.

Comment: Ну вот так получилось, да и я не великий программист. Идея такова - есть некий список задач, у каждой свои данные и свое поведение, а при редактировании пользователю отображается окно с настройками, для каждой задачи, естественно, своё. Плюс данные хранятся в БД (именно поэтому я стал использовать наследование, а не интерфейс, как делал сначала, когда бд еще не была прикручена). Мучаюсь с этим уже давно, и прихожу к выводу, что изначально придумал плохо.

Comment: Ну мы тут все не гении. Смотрите, что легко обобщается, обобщайте, а что с трудом, ну так и бог с ним. В любом случае switch по типу — это не очень хорошо. Лучше наверное закодировать нужную функциональность в конкретном типе. В любом случае, функция получения VM по модели должна быть не нужна: логика программы обычно находится в VM, и каждая VM-ка по идее создаёт себе модель (или берёт из какого-нибудь известного места).

Comment: Да это все достаточно очевидно, но сколько я не бьюсь, лучшего решения не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вашу задачу идеально ложится паттерн [Visitor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

```
abstract class Model
{
    public abstract void Visit(IModelVisitor visitor);
}

class ModelA : Model
{
    public override void Visit(IModelVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

class ModelB : Model
{
    public override void Visit(IModelVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

interface IModelVisitor
{
    void Visit(ModelA modelA);
    void Visit(ModelB modelB);
}

abstract class ViewModel { /* ... */ }

class ViewModelA : ViewModel
{
    public ViewModelA(ModelA modelA) { /* ... */ }
}

class ViewModelB : ViewModel
{
    public ViewModelB(ModelB modelB) { /* ... */ }
}

class ViewModelFactory : IModelVisitor
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public ViewModel CreateViewModel(Model model)
    {
        model.Visit(this);
        return _viewModel;
    }

    void IModelVisitor.Visit(ModelA modelA)
    {
        _viewModel = new ViewModelA(modelA);
    }

    void IModelVisitor.Visit(ModelB modelB)
    {
        _viewModel = new ViewModelB(modelB);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var factory = new ViewModelFactory();
var viewModel = factory.CreateViewModel(new ModelB()); // returns ViewModelB.
```

Comment: Запилил, работает, но я как-то не вижу в чем профит, на вид те же яйца только сбоку)

Comment: Профит в том, что вместо блока `switch` используется один из принципов ООП -- полиморфизм. Блоки `switch`, разбросанные по коду, никак не защищают вас от ошибок, в отличие от Visitor, в котором просто нельзя добавить новый класс в иерархию, не обновив при этом `IModelVisitor` и соответствующие  реализации.

Comment: Ну да, погонял и сам осознал, разве что просто непривычно. Спасибо